# Will I be able to get a list of registered event handlers on a DOM node inside a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, dom-events

I don't know a thing about implementing extensions in Firefox, but having not seen an extension that does anything like this in the Mozilla's addons page, I don't believe it is possible, but thought I will ask about it anyway.

Comment: Don't put your question in the title, and then refer to it from the body. Put it all in  your post, and only a short title for the title.

Comment: Ok, I thought it would save people's effort in deciding whether a question is worth their time or not. A vague short title won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Firefox 3.6: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448602

Answer (score 2):

Answer seems to be 'not yet'.  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html says

> One problem of the current implementation of W3C’s event registration model is that you can’t find out if any event handlers are already registered to an element.

and

> Only in its very recent [DOM Level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20020208/changes.html) W3C adds an `eventListenerList` to store a list of event handlers that are currently registered on an element. This functionality is not yet supported by any browser, it’s too new.